# Same text but nonzero diff

Tags: linux, file, diff

I have two files, the contents of which are exactly same as it appears to my eyes, however, the diff of both shows all lines being different, the reason i suspect has something to do with character format/encoding but i am not sure.

The output of "file --mime" on both is same.

Can someone enlighten me on whats going on? and how could i possibly change one form to another, some command/tool.

Comment: This isn't enough information.  One thing you can try is looking at the output of `hd`, or viewing the files in a hex editor.

Comment: Line endings perhaps? Apply `fromdos` to both files, and diff again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe line endings? Try `dos2unix` and `unix2dos`.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably line endings. Is one from a Unix machine and the other from a Windows machine, by any chance?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Common_problems